# Xamarin (Forms or Native) and player with DRM (ProtectionInfo)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, avplayer, exoplayer

I'm looking around for finding a way to play a video with `DRM` (or `ProtectionInfo`) with the native players, `ExoPlayer` for `Android` or `AVPlayer` for `iOS`.

Basically, I have some protected content in Azure Media Player and want to play them but I can't find any example.

Is there any examples for that? Is it possible to use `Xamarin.Forms` or I have to use native applications?

Comment: Not familiar with DRM and find a link that maybe help: [How to support DRM?](https://github.com/adamfisher/Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer/issues/133). You can use custom renderer as the comment said in each platform to achieve your requirement.

Comment: The main problem is I can't find any documentation how to play a `manifest` from Azure Media Player into ExoPlayer or AVPlayer. All examples use mp4 files or similar.

Answer (score 0):

iOS:
to implement DRM on client app you need asset URL (in HLS/m3u8 format) and FairPlay certificate URL, here is a simple implementation [click](https://github.com/josejuanqm/VersaPlayer/blob/master/VersaPlayer/Classes/Source/Core/Player/VersaPlayer.swift).

Android:
Exoplayer already supports DRM you only need an asset URL with DRM (in DASH format), set in the ExoPlayer and it'll work.

Comment: My URL is a manifest from Azure Media Service not a file. Do you have an example for Android and iOS? Thank you in advance!

Comment: sorry, DRM assets are privates, I don't have one for testing. keep in mind that you have to implement FairPlay for iOS, Widevine for android and PlayReady for Microsoft on Azure Media because those are different.

Comment: Yes, I know that and it is what I'm doing.